# How to quickly find closest matrix

Tags: algorithm, search, matrix

I have an `MxN` matrix, `A`, and a set of matrices with the same number of columns, but with varying number of rows, `{B1, B2..., Bn}`, all using floating-point values. I would like to find the `B` matrix closest to `A` as fast as possible.

A trivial but slow implementation could use matrix-wise least-squares, but if the number of matrices `B` is very high, that becomes a problem for me (two arithmetic functions per element per matrix).

I've read somewhere that Youtube's audio fingerprinting algorithm was using a [finite state transducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer), but I'm not sure how I would implement that, or if it's overkill (i.e. time-consuming to write).

For example, since the number of columns is the same in `A` and `B`, should I try to generate a "letter" from each row of `A`, creating a "string" of `N` letters (for the `N` rows of `A`) and then do fuzzy string searching through the `B` set? How then to make sure the number of letters are small enough? What is a good way to fussy match such rows (is "bbbd" closer to "acae" or "dddg")? I guess this is where the incomprehensible *transducing* comes in...

Comment: If you can turn this into the problem of finding the nearest neighbour in a mult-dimensional space there are libraries you can use such as https://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/

Comment: I doubt you're going to get anything much better than the trivial solution unless there are additional properties of `B` matrices that you haven't mentioned. You have to iterate over all of the elements in `B` anyways